# Suppose N is any positive integer. Add the digits of N to obtain a smaller integer.

Tags: number-theory

Suppose N is any positive integer. Add the digits of N to obtain a smaller
integer. Repeat this process of digit-addition till you get a single digit number
n. Find the number of positive integers N ≤ 1000, such that the final
single-digit number n is equal to 5.

Comment: this might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s(n)$ be the sum of digits function. Then $n\equiv s(n)\pmod{9}$, and by induction
$$
n\equiv s(\cdots(s(n))\cdots)\pmod{9}.
$$
Since the last obtained number is $5$ then it equivalent to find the number of positive integers which have remainder $5$ modulo $9$, i.e., $\lfloor 1000/9\rfloor=111$.

Comment: why "positive integers which have remainder 5 modulo 9 will be [1000/9]"? please explain.

Comment: You just pick one integer every nine consecutive ones...

Comment: first will be 5 then 14 then 23.... last will be 999?

Comment: $999$ has not remainder $5$ when it is divided by $9$; the last one is $995$..